# C# forms using bootstrap buttons

Tags: c#, forms, twitter-bootstrap

is there a way how I can use Bootstrap buttons or something like that in C# Forms?
I already discovered metro modern, but I'm looking for something like bootstrap.

Comment: Bootstrap? Like in http://getbootstrap.com?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but Bootstrap is for web projects. So there's not a way to use them in winforms.

The workound may be creating a web project, publishing it and placing a WebBrowser in your form application. But either way you need to deal with web projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Button class and set the fonts, colors, size etc..
related post is:
[How to customize Button Control like this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334921/how-to-customize-button-control-like-this-one)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WPF animation to extend the button behaviour, but you can not use the bootstrap library because it's only for the web project.