# Circular RadioButton List in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, gdi+

I have designed the circular button list in web application using a jquery [plugin](http://styopdev.github.io/multiPicker/) and html. In this design user at a time select one day only like radio button list. The design is shown below:

[image]

How can I implement the the same design and functionality in windows form? Please help me, from where I am going to started to achieve this one.

Comment: Is it WPF or WinForms?

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei i want this in winform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple options to perform this in windows forms. As an option you can start with customizing `RadioButton` and `Panel` controls. You can create a new class derived from `Panel` and a new class derived from `RadioButton`, then override [`OnPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of those classes and draw the desired presentation.

Here is the result of a sample implementation which I shared in this post:

[image]

**Custom Panel**

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        this.Padding = new Padding(2);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            var d = this.Padding.All;
            var r = this.Height - 2 * d;
            path.AddArc(d, d, r, r, 90, 180);
            path.AddArc(this.Width - r - d, d, r, r, -90, 180);
            path.CloseFigure();
            using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Silver, d))
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, path);
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Radio Button**

```
public class MyRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public MyRadioButton()
    {
        this.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
        this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPaintBackground(e);
        using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            var c = e.Graphics.ClipBounds;
            var r = this.ClientRectangle;
            r.Inflate(-FlatAppearance.BorderSize, -FlatAppearance.BorderSize);
            path.AddEllipse(r);
            e.Graphics.SetClip(path);
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.SetClip(c);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            if (this.Checked)
            {
                using (var p = new Pen(FlatAppearance.BorderColor, 
                                       FlatAppearance.BorderSize))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, r);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Required usings**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: @Phani Thank you, it's not perfect, but it's a good start point :)

Comment: hi @Reza Aghaei, thank u so much.its working awesome.

Comment: hi @Reza Aghaei, we getting yash color when mouseover to the circle. i want yashcolor to circle during button click only.can u suggest me.

Comment: You're welcome :) If I understand your question correctly, if you don't need highlight color on mouse over, you can set `FlatAppearace.MouseOverBackColor` to `Color.Transparent`. This way it's better to set the `Cursor` to `Cursors.Hand` to let the user know when the mouse is over the radio button.

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei, thank u once again, if i have any doubt please suggest me.

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei, hi have one more doubt like this can we implement toogle switch cotrol like the shown in below link http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Material-Design-Toggle-Switch-Plugin-with-jQuery-ToggleSwitch/. is it possible can u suggest me.

Comment: Everything is possible, for example you can use the same techniques used in this answer to draw circular shapes for a checkbox. You can do it in Windows Forms the same way this answer created round radio buttons. But probably using WPF and Universal Windows Apps is a better option.

Comment: Take a look at [Toggle Switches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/toggles) or read more about [Universal Windows App Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/index).

Comment: Another important note is such questions requesting the whole code for a component is off-topic in stackoverflow and users should write their codes and if they had a problem in code ask their question. Usually you get downvote for such questions and your question will be closed if you ask for such questions. Such users will be considered as [Help Vampires](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) which is not acceptable.

Comment: Another important note, it's better to use only a single user in site. Take a look at this post for more information: [What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts) I hope my comments help you to use site better and help you to receive high quality answers from users :)

Comment: Ask a new question containing a code, a MyCheckBox which derived from CheckBox and try to draw the round background like I did in MyPanel control. And ask what is the problem now and what is the goal. Then I'll post an answer for you :)

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei thank u so much for urs suggestion.i can do the same wt u say.

Comment: You're welcome, let me know if you asked a new question about that.

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei, here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431674/unable-to-getting-the-toggle-switch-functionality-in-winforms.

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei, how are u, i am urs follower,i have one doubt in Windows services in .net. can u help me.

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei, can u sugget me sir ,for completing my task related to windows service.

Comment: Hi @GOPALYADAV I took a look at the new question and unfortunately I had no idea about the solution.

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei, here is my question link

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei,here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014736/windows-service-doesnt-run-at-regular-intervals?noredirect=1#comment65380515_39014736, if u have any answer, suggest me please.

Comment: No need to the link. I found [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014736/windows-service-doesnt-run-at-regular-intervals) at top of list of your questions. As I said, unfortunately I have no idea about the solution, hope other users help you to find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Hii Gopal you can achive this functionality using custom control.Goodluck
please refer these links

1. [How to customize Button Control like this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334921/how-to-customize-button-control-like-this-one)
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4te2zh2(v=vs.90).aspx
3. [How do I create button with rounded corners/edges on Winform C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121968/how-do-i-create-button-with-rounded-corners-edges-on-winform-c)

Comment: hi @Phani, please provide me proper link.

Answer (score -1):

You can start with a list view or list box 
Change the item template as a button and add style to your button as you need.
Make the selection mode of the list view as Single.

Comment: Windows Forms ListView or ListBox doesn't have such `ItemTemplate` property.

Comment: hi @Reza Aghaei, i want this  in winform.

Comment: I don't really think this is possible with winforms listview.

Comment: hi @Joseph is it possible in wpf

Comment: @ Gopal obviously you can do that in wpf.You have the flexibility to edit the item template and control template of listview, this way you can achieve this.Try with my answer.

Comment: @Joseph While I believe it's completely possible in WPF too, but I edited the tags based on OP comment and removed WPF. I hope it's not the reason for downvoter and hope it doesn't make a misunderstanding :) I posted a WinForms answer, hope you find it useful.