# windows service doesn't run at regular intervals

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have developed windows service for checking some services running or not for every two minutes.if the services are not running then start them automatically.

here is my code

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            this.CheckServices();

            this.ScheduleService();


        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            this.Schedular.Dispose();
        }




        public void CheckServices()
        {

            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
            log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service1));
            try
            {

                string[] arr1 = new string[] { "CaseWorksCachingService", "Te.Service" };
                for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
                {
                    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(arr1[i]);

                    service.Refresh();

                    if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                    {
                        service.Start();

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Error Message: " + ex.Message.ToString(), ex);
            }


        }

        //ScheduleService Method

        private Timer Schedular;


        public void ScheduleService()
        {
            try
            {
                Schedular = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SchedularCallback));
                string mode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mode"].ToUpper();


                //Set the Default Time.
                DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.MinValue;



                if (mode.ToUpper() == "INTERVAL")
                {
                    //Get the Interval in Minutes from AppSettings.
                    int intervalMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntervalMinutes"]);

                    //Set the Scheduled Time by adding the Interval to Current Time.
                    scheduledTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes);
                    if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                    {
                        //If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next Interval.
                        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes);
                    }
                }

                TimeSpan timeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);


                //Get the difference in Minutes between the Scheduled and Current Time.
                int dueTime = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);

                //Change the Timer's Due Time.
                Schedular.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


                //Stop the Windows Service.
                using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("MyFirstService"))
                {
                    serviceController.Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SchedularCallback(object e)
        {
            //this.WriteToFile("Simple Service Log: {0}");
            this.CheckServices();
            this.ScheduleService();
        }
    }
```

and here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>
    <!-- <add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>-->
    <add key ="IntervalMinutes" value ="2"/>

  </appSettings>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=2.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
  </configSections>
  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="C:\\mylogfile1.txt" />
      <!-- the location where the log file would be created -->
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Error: "The Windows Search service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs"

Comment: You stop the service - well, _a_ service - in the catch block of `ScheduleService` without logging why.

Comment: Well, if something's going wrong inside `ScheduleService` you're never going to find out about it since you swallow the exception (for no real reason, since unhandled exceptions will tend to tear down the service anyway, without requiring you to write any code)

Comment: hi @stuartd, if any exceptions ocured in scheduling , i am stopping the service.is it wrong,i don't know wt is the error. can u suggest me where i am doing wrong in my code.

Comment: hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, suggest me where i am doing wrong in my code.

Comment: We don't know. You don't know. Nobody knows. As a first step, either add a line of logging inside the `catch` inside `ScheduleService` or (better) just remove the `try`/`catch` block entirely.

Comment: hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the ScheduleService won'be call be called,because there is no log is enterd even i maintain the log inside catch block

Comment: hi @stuartd, can u sugget me,how to trace and resolve the issue.

Comment: Add logging to see where and why the service is exiting.

Comment: First of all, what does the event log say? Secondly: Why do you stop the service if an error occurs in scheduling? Thirdly (and I mean it): **stop using the ConfigurationManager class the way you do! Instead use the properties Visual Studio creates for you in `Properties.Settings.Default`**! Why is everybody doing this nonsense??

Comment: hi @ThorstenDittmar thanks ,i understand but where i am putting the time interval.can u suggest me.

Comment: No, you don't understand :-) I'm not saying "stop using the builtin settings mechanism"! I'm saying: Stop using the `ConfigurationManager` class! Using Visual Studio's builtin settings designer you **already have** propertly typed properties named `Properties.Settings.Default.IntervalMinutes` and `Properties.Settings.Default.Mode` - no need to access them using that `ConfigurationManager` thing. Thumbs up for using the settings at all, thumbs down for the way you're accessig them!

Answer (score 0):

There may very well be an exception occurring that is causing your service to exit prematurely.  That is worth looking into.  However, I suspect the actual cause of your problem is that your service is simply exiting immediately after executing the `OnStart()` method.  Windows services do not automatically stay running.  If the `OnStart()` method does not kick off a foreground thread that keeps the service running, you will see the exact error that you are receiving.  I've tried executing your code in a local console application, and once the `OnStart()` method finished, the console application exits.

To keep your service running until it is shutdown, start a foreground thread in the `OnStart()` method.  The following is a working example.

```
using System.Threading;
private ManualResetEvent _shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private Thread _thread;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _thread = new Thread(WorkerThreadFunc);
    _thread.Name = "My Worker Thread";
    _thread.IsBackground = false;
    _thread.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    this.Schedular.Dispose();
    this._shutdownEvent.Set();
    this._thread.Join(3000);
}

private void WorkerThreadFunc()
{
    this.CheckServices();
    this.ScheduleService();

    // This while loop will continue to run, keeping the thread alive,
    // until the OnStop() method is called.
    while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Nothing else needs to change.

If you want to debug your service, put a call to System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() at the beginning of your `OnStart()` method and compile in debug.  When you start the service, you will be prompted to start a debugging session.  You should be able to set breakpoints and debug normally at that point, assuming you have sufficient privileges on the machine.

HTH

Comment: The timer actually should keep the service running, as it spawns a new thread already?

Comment: It's a background thread, which won't keep the process running.

Comment: Then he could use a System.Timers.Timer, which will.

Comment: No, both System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer execute the callbacks on the ThreadPool, which by definition, are background threads.  To see this, create a simple console application, create either timer in Main(), and start it.  When you return from Main(), the application exits because there is no longer a foreground keeping the process alive.  Trust me on this.  A Windows service requires a foreground thread to keep things running.  The two timers being discussed are not sufficient.

Comment: hi @MattDavis, i need  SchedularCallback  method or not.

Comment: I know about services needing a foreground thread, I've written more than a couple of them. I was pretty sure I'd used `System.Timers.Timer` to keep them alive, but now that you mention it, it might also be our company's logging component, which uses a thread to log asynchronously (I know... why not use Log4Net...), so that one might keep the service alive...

Comment: hi @MattDavis , wt u said finallay ,even i used your's code the service doesn't run regularly

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar that makes sense to me.

Comment: hi @MattDavis, even i am using yours code ,the service doesn't run at regular intervals.

Comment: hi @MattDavis thanks ,but i have one doubt,actually My task implementing the service to check the status of services,if they are stopped then starting them.My task successfully executed. i am getting the problem when i using the log4net libarary to log the exceptions if the checking service doesn't installed in system. for that i am using try/catch block in checkservice method after that only the error is occured and the service doesn't work properly.

Comment: hi @MattDavis,i find one thing the problem is in check services if the exception occured in try block it is go to the catch block and log the exception and program is terminated doesn't go back to try block.and schedular service doesn't call.can u suggest me

Comment: If an exception is occurring in the catch block, you need to catch that exception, too.  Otherwise, the exception will unwind to the top of the application and cause it to fail.  There's nothing wrong with putting a try-catch around your logging code in the main catch block of your `CheckServices` function.  But note that if your logging is failing, you really need to get that fixed so that you have a way to diagnose errors that occur in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your service is exactly what Matt Davis says in his answer: A service will only stay running if there is a foreground thread spawned in `OnStart`. This is what his code is doing. It just creates a thread that does basically nothing but wait, but that's enough to keep the service running.

The rest of your code can stay the same, apart from one thing. Change your `ScheduleService` method as follows:

```
   public void ScheduleService()
    {
        try
        {
            // Only create timer once
            if (Schedular != null)
                Schedular = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SchedularCallback));

            // Use proper way to get setting
            string mode = Properties.Settings.Default.Mode.ToUpper();

            ...

            if (mode == "INTERVAL")
            {
                // Use proper way to get settings
                int intervalMinutes = Properties.Settings.Default.IntervalMinutes;

                ...
```

---

I know that some people may not consider this an answer, but debugging seems to be the key here and thus I'm going to tell you what I found an easy way to debug a service.

**Step 1**
Extend your service with two methods: One to call `OnStart` and one to call `OnStop`, as the default methods are protected.

```
public void DoStart(string[] args)
{
    OnStart(xyz);
}

public void DoStop()
{
    OnStop();
}
```

**Step 2**
Add a simple GUI. A WinForms form without any controls is enough. Extend the constructor to take an instance of your service class. When the form loads "start your service", when it closes, "stop your service". Depending on how you create the form, you may need to manually reference `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` in your project.

Example:

```
public class ServiceGUI : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private MyService _myService;

    public ServiceGUI(MyService service)
    {
        _myService = service;
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        _myService.DoStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);
        _myService.DoStop();
    }        
}
```

**Step 3**
Let your `Main` method decide whether to run as a service or as a GUI application. The handy `Environment.UserInteractive` property allows you do decide whether the exe was run by some GUI user.

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new ServiceGUI(new MyService()));
}
else
{
    ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() });
}
```

**What can you do now?**
You can start your application as if it were a normal application and actually properly debug, setting breakpoints, inspecting variables etc. Of course I know that you can also attach your debugger to a running process, but in your case you don't have a running process, so this is a good solution to see what the problem is.

Things like your service starting code will probably not work (unless you run Visual Studio as administrator), but that can also be a nice test whether things work when starting your services runs into an error.

Comment: hi @Thorsten Dittmar,u are giving the code for debugging my service.

Comment: I know. I'm currently adding to my answer.

Comment: hi, wt i amasking that ,the code u are provide to me is for debugging or for the implementing my Task.

Comment: The code I provided in my first answer is to help you debug your service to find the error. My improved answer at the top tries to explain the problems I see with your code and offers an improved version.

Comment: hi , i will implement service and get back to u soonly ,if any queries i got,Thaks for giving valuable information.

Comment: hi ,i have one doubt,actually My task implementing the service to check the status of services,if they are stopped then starting them.My task successfully executed. i am getting the problem when i using the log4net libarary to log the exceptions if the checking service doesn't installed in system. for that i am using try/catch block in checkservice method after that only the error is occured.

Comment: hi i am implemented  the  code you are provide to me but even the service doesn't run at regular interval.

Comment: the windows service doesn't  start .

Comment: Changed my answer again. Use Matt's answer, he's right. The problem is the service needs a thread.

Comment: hi , i got one thing from urs code ,i create timer once in my code,now  u are suggest that create only once fine, why i am getting problem only when i am putting try/catch block in checkservices and logging the exception using log4net library.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean? The problem is that having a timer *is not enough* to keep the service running. What happens is this: Windows starts the service, the `OnStart` method is called. It checks your services and then runs the `ScheduleService` method, which may (or may not - exceptions?) create the timer. As there is no thread keeping the service alive, the service ends now, which causes Windows to output the "Service ended" message. This may also happen because of an exception in `ScheduleService`. In that case you end your service before it was in started state.

Comment: This might cause another exception within your exception handler, which would be logged in the Windows Event Log (I'm not sure whether ending a service that is not properly in "Running" state causes an exception or not). Did you look for errors there as I suggested in my comments to the question? You could try another `try-catch-block` around the code that ends the service, logging errors that might happen there.

Comment: hi ,i find one thing the problem is in check services if the exception occured in try block it is go to the catch block and log the exception and program is terminated doesn't go back to try block.and schedular service doesn't call.can u suggest me.

Comment: Program execution **never** goes back from catch to try block. That's not how it works and is no problem in your case as execution continues with the next line after the catch block, which is `ScheduleService` in any case.